# How can i Force a ViewPager to make their Fragments to be recreated?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Scenarios:

I have a Fragment with a `ViewPager`, that it has a `FragmentPagerAdapter` that provides 3 Fragments.

So the first time my application loads, the 3 tab fragments looks just fine.

When I navigate in the application, i do a `FragmentManager.replace` to load another fragment.

When i go back, or navigate to the Main View (the tabbed View) my first and second tabs are blank.

I debugged the app, and the `Fragment.onDestroyView` never gets call on the Tab fragment, so when it shows again, the `Fragment.onCreateView` never gets called again, so my view is blank.

If I navigate to the third Tab in the Tabbed Fragment, then the `Fragment.onDestroy` gets called by the `PageAdapter` (i supposed because of the 1 offLimit on the ViewPager)

So, my question is, once another Fragment is loaded in my Activity, and then i go back, or navigate to the Tabbed View, how can i force the `ViewPager`, or the `PageAdapter`, or even the Fragment itself to be recreated.

So far i try to do a `FragmentManager.remove(fragment)` with the TabView without any look, also, every time, i navigate to the Tabbed View i pass a new instance to the `FragmentManager.replace` method, it seems that every time, he pulls the same object from the `FragmentManager`.

TabView (Fragment):

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_view, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_iam);
    final PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

PageAdapter:

```
private static class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private Fragment[] tabs;
    private String[] names;

    public MyFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        tabs = new Fragment[]{new FlightsView(), new MyFlightsRequestView(),
                new MyFlightsView()};
        names = new String[]{"VUELOS", "SOLICITUDES", "MIS VUELOS"};
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        return names[position];
    }

}
```

FlightsView (One of the Tab Fragments)

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_flight, container, false);
    recycle_view = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you please try to extend your adapter from **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** instead of **FragmentPagerAdapter**

Comment: No luck, is the same behavior

Comment: What about using **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getSupportFragmentManager()**

Comment: If it works, then you can mark it as an answer, so other people can find the solution

Comment: How do i do this, the only options that i see, is a FLAG for report abuse or something like that, and an arrow (already click it)

Comment: There must be a tick button under the down-arrow. If you press on it, that means it has solved your problem.